# Use variable from a UserForm in a module

Tags: vba, excel

I have a **User Form** with a CheckBox

```
Public MyVariable As String
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        MyVariable = "ON"
    Else
        MyVariable = "OFF"
    End If
 MsgBox (MyVariable)
 End Sub
```

Here, the variable MyVariable Works well.
But then, in the module:

```
Public MyVariable As String
Sub Calculate()
MsgBox (MyVariable) 'the msgbox is empty!
If MyVariable = "ON" Then
Call Sex
End If
End Sub
```

The variable MyVariable is always empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `Public MyVariable As String` from the userform to the module.  Then both subs will be able to "see" it